# Can't run migrations in Laravel 8: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I don't get why my migrations are failing on a clean install of Laravel 8. This is what am getting:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = bunny and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕ 

      +33 vendor frames 
  34  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I am using Kali linux with a perfect Laravel environment, but version 8 just won't work.

Comment: This indicates that it can't resolve the IP of the database specified in your options (probably your .env file)

Comment: Check in your `.env` file if `DB_HOST` is set properly (and not appears twice, with correct and incorrect value).

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

just in .env file change the value of DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1

"change `DB_HOST=mysql` to `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`"

Comment: I'm glad it was helpfull. @angelito-tan

Comment: From the information in the question, there is no way to know what the problem is, let alone whether or not this answer is applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the value of DB_HOST to 127.0.0.1 within the .env file did not solve my problem completely, I also had to rebuild the whole docker/sail with:

`sail down -v`

and

`sail build --no-cache`

and first then after running

`sail up -d`

I could run:

`./artisan migrate:fresh`

Rebuilding is required when there was changes to the database credentials.

Answer (score 0):

in this case need check the .env file and update `DB_HOST=mysql` to `DB_HOST=localhost`
I got the same issue after install the laravel.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem
I installed two php environments first that of the xamp and the second that of the computer
go to computer location.
"C:\Program Files\php-8.0.3" open file "php.ini"
and add
without `;`

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql
extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
```

And the second
click on the xamp configuration button to change the configuration and add this two line in the file php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql
extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
```

Warning without the semicolon, do not add semicolon `;`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Usually, if the extension was missing, the error would look different