# Can't using php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I create new project laravel and I want to migrate, so I do

```
php artisan serve
```

but why I got

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I do following this advise

[Can't run migrations in Laravel 8: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65237844/cant-run-migrations-in-laravel-8-sqlstatehy000-2002-php-network-getaddress)

to change the value in DB_HOST, but when I checked, it was completely just set like that advice

my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:TqD4fedTyWRixmGVCzmjFHSriROFu/57yZRZeM5YI6Q=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I also do

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

I do change in file database.php
from

```
  'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

to

```
  'charset' => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```

instead of done, it give me

```
  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 
  'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` bigint 
  unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` 
 varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, 
 `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password` varchar(255) not 
 null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp 
 null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 
 collate 'utf8_unicode_ci')
```

when I wrote again, it still got the same way

before this, I wrote migrate and still good, why it's get hard than before?

thank's

Comment: Are you running your DB inner docker container?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `php artisan migrate` laravel runs up the migrations without drop the tables thats why your SQL engine returns that users table already exists, if you are working on a fresh project try using  `php artisan migrate:fresh`
here the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#drop-all-tables-migrate)